# How do I use HTTPS port on clould9 ide?

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide

I am just running some tests on [c9.io](http://c9.io) - but I am stuck on how to get the HTTPS server to run.

I am using the port given in `process.env.PORT` which links up to the browser in c9, but there doesn't seem to an HTTPS port.  In a local environment I use port 3001 for HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud9 workspaces don't support custom SSL certificates yet so you won't be able to start an HTTPS server from there, but your http server running on 0.0.0.0:8080 will be accessible via both HTTP and HTTPS.